# Add Dynamic Content - Azure Data Factory ADF V2

Tags: azure, expression, azure-data-factory

I need to add a Dynamic Content in an ADF. In such a way that it needs to read the  files from the folder with name as  ‘StartDateOfMonth-EndDateOfMonth’ as below format.

Result: 20190601-20190630

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few steps for how you can achieve that:

1. in DataSet:

   - create parameter "Date"
   - set up a connection to one selected file
   - now, replace "File" field with expression, similar to the following:

@concat('filedata_',dataset().Date,'.csv')

2. in Pipeline:

   - when using above DataSet, you just must pass the value, which you can set up by 'Set Variable'